# Create a dictionary based on the request.body output from url and then print it in VF page

Tags: java, dictionary, salesforce, apex

I wish to create a dictionary based on the format like this :

{id:{task:{id:info}}}

from below "results" that received by the request.Body:

results :

{data=({id=ac06e5d3-e291-4af1-b440-08684ff49ffd, valid=false, text=I will do it, task=()}, {id=29c35834-f589-4ffc-a64f-e679eb6fa4c2, valid=true, text=Will have to do a lot of thing, task=({id=380e22c7-abcd-4277-8243-66737c5ca100, info={object=Something, subject=Create myself, time=today、}, sub_task=Sending email})}, {id=cdfe2b80-a8f9-4503-8962-7fcc87e06c0c, valid=true, text=I will have to carried out something, task=({id=719a341f-3660-452d-b929-d869e94513db, info={formation=no need, object=to be told, subject=total value}, sub_task=change value}, {id=9723ffc7-bfef-46f2-9d8d-a809830a27ac, info={object=No idea, subject=Implementing new algorithm}, sub_task=implementation})}), id=3b42e4fe-2939-45eb-aee1-b55f626d8194, ok=true}

Can anyone assist me?

This is for salesforce apex and VF page

My code :

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) 
JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
List<Object> task_candidates = (List<Object>) results.get('data');
for (Object task_candidate: task_candidates) {
    Map<String, Object> candidate = (Map<String, Object>)task_candidate;
    Boolean valid = (Boolean)candidate.get('valid');
    if(valid == True){
        **what to put here?**
        **I wanted it to be in form {id:{task:{id:info}}} **
}
```

My expected output should be like:

example variable to store this dictionary is "a":

{"29c35834-f589-4ffc-a64f-e679eb6fa4c2":{380e22c7-abcd-4277-8243-66737c5ca100:{object=Something, subject=Create myself, time=today、}}}, "cdfe2b80-a8f9-4503-8962-7fcc87e06c0c":{id=719a341f-3660-452d-b929-d869e94513db:{formation=no need, object=to be told, subject=total value}}}

Something like this when print "a".